# How should I spec this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

The following spec works but I know it shouldn't be like this.  I am having a hard time getting my head around rspec, in particular mocks and stubs.

This is the model code

```
class RecipeFermentable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :product

  def set_attributes()
    attrs = product.product_attributes
    self.ppg = attrs.find_by_name(:ppg.to_s).value
    self.ecb = attrs.find_by_name(:ecb.to_s).value
  end
end
```

And this is the spec I have written

```
  it "should set the attributes from the product" do
    @product_attribute1 = mock_model(ProductAttribute, :name => :ppg, :value => 40)
    @product_attribute2 = mock_model(ProductAttribute, :name => :ecb, :value => 1)

    @product = Product.new
    @product.product_attributes << @product_attribute1
    @product.product_attributes << @product_attribute2
    @recipe_fermentable = RecipeFermentable.new
    @recipe_fermentable.product.should_receive(:product_attributes).and_return(@product_attributes)
    @product_attributes.stub(:find_by_name).with(:ppg.to_s).and_return(@product_attribute1)
    @product_attributes.stub(:find_by_name).with(:ecb.to_s).and_return(@product_attribute2)

    @recipe_fermentable.set_attributes

    @recipe_fermentable.ppg.should eql(40)
    @recipe_fermentable.ecb.should eql(1)
 end
```

For a start my spec is way bigger than my method, and I am using a real Product.  Some pointers on the way to write a goodbetter spec for this would be really helpfull.  Also if anyone knows of a good resource for learning rspec using mocks and stubs, please could you add some links.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change a couple of things here:

- Much of the code in your `it` is just providing context, so it should be in your before(:each) block.
- You are setting a message expectation, but it doesn't really seem like you are testing for that. I think the expectation should be switched to a `stub` instead. Another test could be `it 'should call product_attributes'`, where you would in fact test that expectation - I am not advocating you do this since you would be testing implementation and not behavior, but just making the point.
- You are returning @product_attributes in that message expectation, and using it right after to stub the find_by_name calls. However, you never defined @product_attributes. I assume that should be a mock object, and I'm not sure what it *really* is in that context. Maybe it is nil, and you are stubbing a couple of methods on it.

With those two changes, here's where we are:

```
before(:each) do
  @product                = mock_model(Product)
  @product_attribute_ppg  = mock_model(ProductAttribute, :name => :ppg, :value => 40)
  @product_attribute_ecb  = mock_model(ProductAttribute, :name => :ecb, :value => 1)
  @product_attributes     = mock('product_attributes')
  @product_attributes.stub!(:find_by_name).with(:ppg.to_s).and_return(@product_attribute_ppg)
  @product_attributes.stub!(:find_by_name).with(:ecb.to_s).and_return(@product_attribute_ecb)
  @product.stub!(:product_attributes).and_return(@product_attributes)

  @recipe_fermentable = RecipeFermentable.new
  @recipe_fermentable.stub!(:product).and_return(@product)
end

it 'should set the attributes from the product' do
  @recipe_fermentable.set_attributes
  @recipe_fermentable.ppg.should eql(40)
  @recipe_fermentable.ecb.should eql(1)
end
```

With all of that all of the way, I don't completely agree with your approach here. I think that you are repeating data and moving away from DB normalization. Unless there's a real reason for that (could be that your way ahead and for performance reasons you had to do this), I would suggest the following instead:

```
class RecipeFermentable < ActiveRecord::Base
  def ppg
    #rescue nil here so that if attributes is nil, or find_by_name('ppg') is nil, things don't blow up
    product.attributes.find_by_name('ppg').value rescue nil
  end

  #other
end
```

A couple of resources for testing:

- [RSpec book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book)
- [xUnit patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/): not RSpec nor Ruby, but a must.

Comment: Thank you, that makes alot of sense.

The reason I am duplicating data is due to the fact that the product attributes can change over time but the attributes of the recipe need to stay the same. Unless the user wants to change them.